# Assign a tensor to multiple slices

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, slice, tensor

Let

```
a = tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]])
b = torch.tensor([1, 2])
c = tensor([[1, 2, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 2, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Is there a way to obtain `c` by assigning `b` to slices of `a` without any loops? That is, `a[indices] = b` for some `indices` or something similar?

Comment: Would a NumPy version be OK?

Comment: @norok2 I'm using PyTorch but perhaps the NumPy version would work for it too.

Comment: I wrote both NumPy and a PyTorch implementation, along with some explanation for the logic behind.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `scatter` method in pytorch.

```py
a = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0]])

b = torch.tensor([1, 2])

index = torch.tensor([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]])

a.scatter_(1, index, b.view(-1,2).repeat(3,1))
# tensor([[1, 2, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 2, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: While this does not have explicit looping per se, the loop is hidden under the carpet of having defined `index` explicitly. `torch.tensor([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]])` should really be written as: `torch.tensor([list(range(i:len(b)+i) for i in range(num_rows)])` to generalize to arbitrary number of rows. This approach of spelling out the loop may even be considered bad coding practice.

Comment: @norok2 Thanks for the suggestion. I agree and your solution is more general.

Comment: @norok2 to @zihaozhihao's defense: `index` can be generated as `index = torch.stack([torch.arange(0, 3), torch.arange(1, 4)], dim=1)` ;) which is fully vectorized. Although you're right that your approach seems to suit the problem better.

Comment: @Jatentaki This is also spelled out loop. For a generic `len(b)`, this should become: `torch.stack([torch.arange(i, i + num_rows) for i in range(len(b))], dim=1)` and we are back to square one. I agree that `list(range())` should become `torch.arange()` in what I proposed, i.e. `torch.stack([torch.arange(i:len(b)+i) for i in range(num_rows)], dim=0)`. But logically there is no other improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind this operation is a bit iffy in the sense that it is not clear what the parameters of the operation are.
However, one way of obtaining the desired output from the input with vectorized operations only is:

- determine how many rows are needed (`3` for your example)
- create a `a` with a number of columns such that `b` is followed by as many zeros as the number of rows (`2 + 3`), and the choosen number of rows (`3`)
- assign `b` to the beginning of `a` for each
- flatten the array, cut `num_rows` zeros, and reshape to the target shape.

In NumPy, this can be implemented as:

```
import numpy as np


b = np.array([1, 2])
c = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 2, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 2]])

num_rows = 3
a = np.zeros((num_rows, len(b) + num_rows), dtype=b.dtype)
a[:, :len(b)] = b
a = a.ravel()[:-num_rows].reshape((num_rows, len(b) + num_rows - 1))

print(a)
# [[1 2 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 0]
#  [0 0 1 2]]

print(np.all(a == c))
# True
```

---

## EDIT

The same approach implemented in Torch:

```
import torch as to


b = to.tensor([1, 2])
c = to.tensor([[1, 2, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 2, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 2]])

num_rows = 3
a = to.zeros((num_rows, len(b) + num_rows), dtype=b.dtype)
a[:, :len(b)] = b
a = a.flatten()[:-num_rows].reshape((num_rows, len(b) + num_rows - 1))

print(a)
# tensor([[1, 2, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 2, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1, 2]])

print(to.all(a == c))
# tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
```